# Maple -- Lattice Algorithms

Tags: maple, computer-algebra-systems

Is there any place online where I can find the code for an algorithm which computes the shortest vector in a lattice?

The library only includes the algorithm for LLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this paper by Fincke and Pohst:

http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1985-44-170/S0025-5718-1985-0777278-8/S0025-5718-1985-0777278-8.pdf

In particular, algorithm 2.8 on page 465 should help you.

You should be able to find the code for Keith Mathews' implementation somewhere near here:

http://www.numbertheory.org/calc/calc_doc.html